# Ng not working in gitbash but working fine in node command prompt

Tags: node.js, git-bash

i have installed angular/cli  globally, and when i am writing 'ng -v' in node  command prompt prompt its working but same command at  the same directory when i use git bash its  throwing error 'ng is not a command'.

i have also uninstalled and again installed all the dependencies and cleared cache also, this problem seems to come time to time .

```
this is my Environment variable:-
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS 
Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
 Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
 Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
 Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files 
 (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin;C:\Program Files 
 (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS 
 Code\bin;c:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\; C:\Program 
 Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs


this the screeshot of the error.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about Git Bash picking up the environment variables.

In my `~/.bash_profile` I have a line which explicitly adds the `nodejs` directory to $PATH.

```
export PATH="/c/Program Files/nodejs/":$PATH
```